# Removing index from a string using while loop

Tags: python, string, random, indexing, while-loop

I don't know why but the code I wrote isn't running. I'm trying to generate a random index and deleting it from the string. It's not giving me an error message so I don't know what's wrong. Here's what I have:

```
def delete_randomly(string):
  i = 0
  while i < len(string):
    if string[i] == randint(0, 10):
      return string.remove(string[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in an infinite loop. Imagine the string is 'stackoverflow', your code is always comparing string[0] (because i == 0 everytime) with a random number between 0-10. For example

First iteration:

> string[0] = 's'
>
> randint(0, 10) = 3

Second iteration:

> string[0] = 's'
>
> randint(0, 10) = 7

Infinite iteration

> string[0] = 's'
>
> randint(0, 10) = number

Never 's' would be equals to number.

It is also wrong because string class in python has no method named remove.

So if you want remove a valid letter the code is:

```
def delete_randomly(string):
    temp = list(string)
    temp[randint(0, len(string) - 1)] = ""
    return "".join(temp)
```

Comment: `a = randint(0, len(string))` and omit the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition for @Juan Antonio Martinez Lopez answer's, you could also use the following code:

```
def delete_randomly(string):
  randomIndex = randint(0, len(string) - 1)
  return string[:randomIndex] + string[randomIndex + 1:]
```

Comment: It should be len(string) - 1, cause if the string has 7 characters and randint() returns 7, string[7]  is out of the array.

Comment: Thanks! I always make mistakes with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This infinite loop will never break depending on the input. Is this what you trying to achieve?

```
from random import randint
def delete_randomly(string):
  print(f'input string = {string}')
  ran_int = randint(0, len(string))
  print(f'removing index = ({ran_int})')
  new_str = ''
  for idx, val in enumerate(string):
      if idx == ran_int:
          continue
      new_str+=val
  return new_str
print(delete_randomly('abakdkemnaskakac'))
```